# Rust - no implementation for `&Result<_, _> == String`

Tags: rust

I'm trying to make an if statement comparing a String variable and a String to match exact values (without using `match`). Here is my code:

```rust
if &guess.trim().parse() == String::from("quit") { // TODO: Fix this
    println!("Goodbye! The secret number was: {} and you attempted to guess it {} times!", secret_number, tries);
    break;
}
```

`guess` is a `String::new()` which has been assigned a value through user input (`io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess).expect("Unable to read line");`)

When I run the code, I get an error from the above code snippet:

[image: code error]

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error and how to fix it?

I have tried converting `"quit"` to `String::from("quit")` but it seems that the error is to do with the `==` and I'm not sure what `&Result<_, _>` is. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just `if guess.trim() == "quit"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `if guess.trim() == "quit"` fixed my problem. Thank you @eggyal!

Comment: Thanks for this, I forgot that when the user hits the Enter key, it adds a "\n" on mac and "\r\n" on Windows so you have to trim the input. For a little extra handling I added a `to_lowercase()` to the `guess` just in case the user types "Quit" or "QUIT".

Answer (score 2):

In this situation `parse()` was superfluous, but in most other situations you resolve the error "something not implemented for Result" by extracting the actual value from the `Result` and using that rather than the `Result` itself. Your options for that are:

- the `?` operator to extract the value and propagate the error (if one occurred) to the caller,
- the [`unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) or [`expect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect) methods to panic in case of error, and
- pattern matching with `match` or `if let`, to handle the error case locally.

See the [book chapter on `Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) for details.